# MySql Query Unknown Column Error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT a.data 
    FROM Authentications a, Authentications b 
    LEFT JOIN Authentications c ON a.id = c.id
```

Why does this query yield "#1054 - Unknown column 'a.id' in 'on clause'" when

```
SELECT a.data 
    FROM Authentications a
    LEFT JOIN Authentications c ON a.id = c.id
```

is okay?

Comment: why  Authentications b  in first query?

Comment: how are you joining "Authentications b"?

Comment: You're mixing two styles of `JOIN` syntax in your first sample, the second one should be OK, assuming that `Authentications` actually table has `id` field..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing JOIN syntax so the alias that you are using is not available in the `ON` condition.  You should not mix JOIN syntax.

Your query should be:

```
SELECT a.data 
FROM Authentications a
CROSS JOIN Authentications b 
LEFT JOIN Authentications c 
   ON a.id = c.id
```

Or if you are joining the `b`, then you will use:

```
SELECT a.data 
FROM Authentications a
INNER JOIN Authentications b 
  on a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN Authentications c 
   ON a.id = c.id
```

The `JOIN` has a higher precedence over the comma so the alias of `a` is not available for the `ON`.

Comment: @chacham15 This fixes the syntax error. But can you tell us why you are joining thrice the same table? What is the query supposed to do?

Comment: @ypercube Oh, sorry, didnt see that. The table is an id, key, value triplet and Im trying to get three values for the same id (where the third value may or may not be there). I just left off the `WHERE` clause as it was unimportant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

first query you joining b to c and putting on condition on a .

there is no join with a

Answer (score 0):

The 'on' clause must use columns from the tables being joined - something like
SELECT a.data 
    FROM Authentications a, Authentications b 
    LEFT JOIN Authentications c ON b.id = c.id
where a.id = b.id

or something like that